# Android, use library or copy source code?

Tags: java, android, terminal, serial-port

I hope my question is suitable here. I recently started learning android - making buttons, using google maps and other basic stuff. I saw a thread recently (can't find it) about this and I got interested in it: https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki

This is an open source android terminal emulator. It also seems to have a library called `EmulatorView` with which people can call methods etc. What I would like to do is use this app inside my own app. Instead of just looking at the file system on the android phone etc. my app would connect to the console of a serial device like a router, usb to serial. Something I usually use minicom for on my pc. As in there could be a  button in my app and if I press it it opens the console of the attached router and I could issue administrative commands.

I was wondering what the easiest way to do this would be? Would it be to try and use this library and make my own terminal, seems quite hard, or would it be to copy their source into a project and try to edit it? Seems messy to organize everything, and could be hard too? Then use some library like this to connect to the serial device? http://slickdevlabs.com/slick-usb-2-serial-library/

What would the first steps be, make a terminal like the open source app has, use their library or paste in their code? Then try and edit it to do something over serial?

I have tried to use their example for using their library (jackpal.androidterm.sample.telnet), but it crashes when I click `open shell`, I was wondering if this `open shell` button in their example was what I needed?

Comment: [Launching this app via intent](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Launching-Android-Terminal-Emulator-from-another-App) is probably the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Or you can read this: https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Launching-Android-Terminal-Emulator-from-another-App

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the replies, this seems a bit different from what I want however, that would require an installation of android terminal emulator, whereas the solution I want should have all the code in one apk. I need to change what the program does, make it connect to a serial device, rather than just call the program. Maybe I would copy in what they have for their whole android terminal emulator project and work off it, editing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided I would learn more by writing the app myself using the library.